# Why drawing is shifting downside while applying Fe-composite? How to achieve multiple -feComposite Operation in SVG?

Tags: java, svg, image-processing, composite

I am trying to achieve multiple composite operation on path element.
But I am not getting my desire output. Here is my effort,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1599px; height: 888px; position: absolute;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="myfilter">
            <feImage xlink:href="#layer1" result="lay1"/>
            <feImage xlink:href="#layer2" result="lay2"/>
            <feImage xlink:href="#layer3" result="lay3"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#layer4" result="lay4"/>

            <feComposite operator="in" in="lay2" in2="lay1" result="lay1in3"/>
            <feComposite operator="in" in="lay1in3" in2="lay3" result="lay1in4" />
<!--       <feComposite operator="in" in="lay1in4" in2="lay1in3" result="lay1in5" /> -->
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g filter="url(#myfilter)" alignment-baseline="middle" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" text-anchor="middle">
        <svg id="layer1" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g >
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(217, 217, 52, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(217, 217, 52, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" >
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 0.001335 57.1737 C 0.000611326 57.6053 0.342416 57.9597 0.773785 57.9745 L 0.79942 57.975 L 17.7699 58.0157 C 18.3212 58.017 18.7675 58.4644 18.7675 59.0157 L 18.7675 76.4727 C 18.7675 76.685 18.8518 76.8885 19.0019 77.0385 C 19.1521 77.1886 19.3556 77.2728 19.5679 77.2727 L 105.325 77.2323 C 105.766 77.2321 106.124 76.874 106.124 76.4323 L 106.124 59.1769 C 106.124 58.6246 106.572 58.1769 107.124 58.1769 L 124.392 58.1769 C 124.834 58.1769 125.192 57.8187 125.192 57.3769 L 125.192 0.8 C 125.192 0.358172 124.834 0 124.392 0 L 0.895565 0 C 0.454255 -1.11388e-006 0.0962964 0.357361 0.09556 0.79867 L 0.001335 57.1737 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="layer2" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g >
                <rect style="fill: rgb(5, 134, 48); stroke: #000000;" x="0" y="0" width="1599" height="888" />
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g>
                        <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                            <g fill="rgba(5, 134, 48, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(5, 134, 48, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" >
                                <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 5.6025 2.3717 C 5.6025 1.39139 4.80781 0.5967 3.8275 0.5967 C 2.84719 0.5967 2.0525 1.39139 2.0525 2.3717 C 2.0525 3.35201 2.84719 4.1467 3.8275 4.1467 C 4.80781 4.1467 5.6025 3.35201 5.6025 2.3717 M 10.6063 14.0557 C 10.6063 13.0754 9.81161 12.2807 8.8313 12.2807 C 7.85099 12.2807 7.0563 13.0754 7.0563 14.0557 C 7.0563 15.036 7.85099 15.8307 8.8313 15.8307 C 9.81161 15.8307 10.6063 15.036 10.6063 14.0557 M 22.0363 14.0557 C 22.0363 13.0754 21.2416 12.2807 20.2613 12.2807 C 19.281 12.2807 18.4863 13.0754 18.4863 14.0557 C 18.4863 15.036 19.281 15.8307 20.2613 15.8307 C 21.2416 15.8307 22.0363 15.036 22.0363 14.0557 M 64.5813 39.2017 C 64.5813 38.2214 63.7866 37.4267 62.8063 37.4267 C 61.826 37.4267 61.0313 38.2214 61.0313 39.2017 C 61.0313 40.182 61.826 40.9767 62.8063 40.9767 C 63.7866 40.9767 64.5813 40.182 64.5813 39.2017 M 76.4431 10.8299 C 76.4431 9.84959 75.6484 9.0549 74.6681 9.0549 C 73.6878 9.0549 72.8931 9.84959 72.8931 10.8299 C 72.8931 11.8102 73.6878 12.6049 74.6681 12.6049 C 75.6484 12.6049 76.4431 11.8102 76.4431 10.8299 M 120.842 17.9165 C 120.842 16.9362 120.048 16.1415 119.067 16.1415 C 118.087 16.1415 117.292 16.9362 117.292 17.9165 C 117.292 18.8968 118.087 19.6915 119.067 19.6915 C 120.048 19.6915 120.842 18.8968 120.842 17.9165 M 123.713 2.3717 C 123.713 1.39139 122.918 0.5967 121.938 0.5967 C 120.957 0.5967 120.162 1.39139 120.162 2.3717 C 120.162 3.35201 120.957 4.1467 121.938 4.1467 C 122.918 4.1467 123.713 3.35201 123.713 2.3717 M 73.9539 70.7231 C 73.9539 69.7428 73.1592 68.9481 72.1789 68.9481 C 71.1986 68.9481 70.4039 69.7428 70.4039 70.7231 C 70.4039 71.7034 71.1986 72.4981 72.1789 72.4981 C 73.1592 72.4981 73.9539 71.7034 73.9539 70.7231 M 10.6741 20.3557 C 10.6741 20.0658 10.439 19.8307 10.1491 19.8307 C 9.85915 19.8307 9.6241 20.0658 9.6241 20.3557 C 9.6241 20.6456 9.85915 20.8807 10.1491 20.8807 C 10.439 20.8807 10.6741 20.6456 10.6741 20.3557 M 13.2141 20.3557 C 13.2141 20.0658 12.979 19.8307 12.6891 19.8307 C 12.3992 19.8307 12.1641 20.0658 12.1641 20.3557 C 12.1641 20.6456 12.3992 20.8807 12.6891 20.8807 C 12.979 20.8807 13.2141 20.6456 13.2141 20.3557 M 15.7541 20.3557 C 15.7541 20.0658 15.519 19.8307 15.2291 19.8307 C 14.9392 19.8307 14.7041 20.0658 14.7041 20.3557 C 14.7041 20.6456 14.9392 20.8807 15.2291 20.8807 C 15.519 20.8807 15.7541 20.6456 15.7541 20.3557 M 18.2941 20.3557 C 18.2941 20.0658 18.059 19.8307 17.7691 19.8307 C 17.4792 19.8307 17.2441 20.0658 17.2441 20.3557 C 17.2441 20.6456 17.4792 20.8807 17.7691 20.8807 C 18.059 20.8807 18.2941 20.6456 18.2941 20.3557 M 19.5641 22.8957 C 19.5641 22.6058 19.3291 22.3707 19.0391 22.3707 C 18.7492 22.3707 18.5141 22.6058 18.5141 22.8957 C 18.5141 23.1856 18.7492 23.4207 19.0391 23.4207 C 19.3291 23.4207 19.5641 23.1856 19.5641 22.8957 M 17.0241 22.8957 C 17.0241 22.6058 16.789 22.3707 16.4991 22.3707 C 16.2092 22.3707 15.9741 22.6058 15.9741 22.8957 C 15.9741 23.1856 16.2092 23.4207 16.4991 23.4207 C 16.789 23.4207 17.0241 23.1856 17.0241 22.8957 M 14.4841 22.8957 C 14.4841 22.6058 14.249 22.3707 13.9591 22.3707 C 13.6692 22.3707 13.4341 22.6058 13.4341 22.8957 C 13.4341 23.1856 13.6692 23.4207 13.9591 23.4207 C 14.249 23.4207 14.4841 23.1856 14.4841 22.8957 M 11.9441 22.8957 C 11.9441 22.6058 11.709 22.3707 11.4191 22.3707 C 11.1292 22.3707 10.8941 22.6058 10.8941 22.8957 C 10.8941 23.1856 11.1292 23.4207 11.4191 23.4207 C 11.709 23.4207 11.9441 23.1856 11.9441 22.8957 M 49.7327 7.3772 C 49.7327 6.97679 49.4081 6.6522 49.0077 6.6522 C 48.6073 6.6522 48.2827 6.97679 48.2827 7.3772 C 48.2827 7.77761 48.6073 8.1022 49.0077 8.1022 C 49.4081 8.1022 49.7327 7.77761 49.7327 7.3772 M 54.8127 7.3772 C 54.8127 6.97679 54.4881 6.6522 54.0877 6.6522 C 53.6873 6.6522 53.3627 6.97679 53.3627 7.3772 C 53.3627 7.77761 53.6873 8.1022 54.0877 8.1022 C 54.4881 8.1022 54.8127 7.77761 54.8127 7.3772 M 59.8927 7.3772 C 59.8927 6.97679 59.5681 6.6522 59.1677 6.6522 C 58.7673 6.6522 58.4427 6.97679 58.4427 7.3772 C 58.4427 7.77761 58.7673 8.1022 59.1677 8.1022 C 59.5681 8.1022 59.8927 7.77761 59.8927 7.3772 M 51.3887 41.812 C 51.3887 41.4116 51.0641 41.087 50.6637 41.087 C 50.2633 41.087 49.9387 41.4116 49.9387 41.812 C 49.9387 42.2124 50.2633 42.537 50.6637 42.537 C 51.0641 42.537 51.3887 42.2124 51.3887 41.812 M 51.3887 46.892 C 51.3887 46.4916 51.0641 46.167 50.6637 46.167 C 50.2633 46.167 49.9387 46.4916 49.9387 46.892 C 49.9387 47.2924 50.2633 47.617 50.6637 47.617 C 51.0641 47.617 51.3887 47.2924 51.3887 46.892 M 50.5156 62.8464 C 50.5156 62.446 50.191 62.1214 49.7906 62.1214 C 49.3902 62.1214 49.0656 62.446 49.0656 62.8464 C 49.0656 63.2468 49.3902 63.5714 49.7906 63.5714 C 50.191 63.5714 50.5156 63.2468 50.5156 62.8464 M 50.5156 67.9264 C 50.5156 67.526 50.191 67.2014 49.7906 67.2014 C 49.3902 67.2014 49.0656 67.526 49.0656 67.9264 C 49.0656 68.3268 49.3902 68.6514 49.7906 68.6514 C 50.191 68.6514 50.5156 68.3268 50.5156 67.9264 M 119.34 54.4877 C 119.34 54.0873 119.015 53.7627 118.615 53.7627 C 118.214 53.7627 117.89 54.0873 117.89 54.4877 C 117.89 54.8881 118.214 55.2127 118.615 55.2127 C 119.015 55.2127 119.34 54.8881 119.34 54.4877 M 119.34 49.4077 C 119.34 49.0073 119.015 48.6827 118.615 48.6827 C 118.214 48.6827 117.89 49.0073 117.89 49.4077 C 117.89 49.8081 118.214 50.1327 118.615 50.1327 C 119.015 50.1327 119.34 49.8081 119.34 49.4077 M 119.34 44.3277 C 119.34 43.9273 119.015 43.6027 118.615 43.6027 C 118.214 43.6027 117.89 43.9273 117.89 44.3277 C 117.89 44.7281 118.214 45.0527 118.615 45.0527 C 119.015 45.0527 119.34 44.7281 119.34 44.3277 M 18.6175 77.1231 L 18.6175 77.4231 L 18.9175 77.4231 L 18.9175 77.1231 L 18.6175 77.1231 M 105.974 77.0819 L 105.974 77.3819 L 106.274 77.3819 L 106.274 77.0819 L 105.974 77.0819 M 125.042 -0.15 L 125.042 0.15 L 125.342 0.15 L 125.342 -0.15 L 125.042 -0.15 M -0.0531 -0.15 L -0.0531 0.15 L 0.2469 0.15 L 0.2469 -0.15 L -0.0531 -0.15 Z" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="layer3" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g >
                <svg id="layer4" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(227, 227, 227, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(227, 227, 227, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" >
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 10.5491 20.3557 C 10.5491 20.1348 10.37 19.9557 10.1491 19.9557 C 9.92819 19.9557 9.7491 20.1348 9.7491 20.3557 C 9.7491 20.5766 9.92819 20.7557 10.1491 20.7557 C 10.37 20.7557 10.5491 20.5766 10.5491 20.3557 M 13.0891 20.3557 C 13.0891 20.1348 12.91 19.9557 12.6891 19.9557 C 12.4682 19.9557 12.2891 20.1348 12.2891 20.3557 C 12.2891 20.5766 12.4682 20.7557 12.6891 20.7557 C 12.91 20.7557 13.0891 20.5766 13.0891 20.3557 M 15.6291 20.3557 C 15.6291 20.1348 15.45 19.9557 15.2291 19.9557 C 15.0082 19.9557 14.8291 20.1348 14.8291 20.3557 C 14.8291 20.5766 15.0082 20.7557 15.2291 20.7557 C 15.45 20.7557 15.6291 20.5766 15.6291 20.3557 M 18.1691 20.3557 C 18.1691 20.1348 17.99 19.9557 17.7691 19.9557 C 17.5482 19.9557 17.3691 20.1348 17.3691 20.3557 C 17.3691 20.5766 17.5482 20.7557 17.7691 20.7557 C 17.99 20.7557 18.1691 20.5766 18.1691 20.3557 M 19.4391 22.8957 C 19.4391 22.6748 19.26 22.4957 19.0391 22.4957 C 18.8182 22.4957 18.6391 22.6748 18.6391 22.8957 C 18.6391 23.1166 18.8182 23.2957 19.0391 23.2957 C 19.26 23.2957 19.4391 23.1166 19.4391 22.8957 M 16.8991 22.8957 C 16.8991 22.6748 16.72 22.4957 16.4991 22.4957 C 16.2782 22.4957 16.0991 22.6748 16.0991 22.8957 C 16.0991 23.1166 16.2782 23.2957 16.4991 23.2957 C 16.72 23.2957 16.8991 23.1166 16.8991 22.8957 M 14.3591 22.8957 C 14.3591 22.6748 14.18 22.4957 13.9591 22.4957 C 13.7382 22.4957 13.5591 22.6748 13.5591 22.8957 C 13.5591 23.1166 13.7382 23.2957 13.9591 23.2957 C 14.18 23.2957 14.3591 23.1166 14.3591 22.8957 M 11.8191 22.8957 C 11.8191 22.6748 11.64 22.4957 11.4191 22.4957 C 11.1982 22.4957 11.0191 22.6748 11.0191 22.8957 C 11.0191 23.1166 11.1982 23.2957 11.4191 23.2957 C 11.64 23.2957 11.8191 23.1166 11.8191 22.8957 M 49.6077 7.3772 C 49.6077 7.04583 49.3391 6.7772 49.0077 6.7772 C 48.6763 6.7772 48.4077 7.04583 48.4077 7.3772 C 48.4077 7.70857 48.6763 7.9772 49.0077 7.9772 C 49.3391 7.9772 49.6077 7.70857 49.6077 7.3772 M 54.6877 7.3772 C 54.6877 7.04583 54.4191 6.7772 54.0877 6.7772 C 53.7563 6.7772 53.4877 7.04583 53.4877 7.3772 C 53.4877 7.70857 53.7563 7.9772 54.0877 7.9772 C 54.4191 7.9772 54.6877 7.70857 54.6877 7.3772 M 59.7677 7.3772 C 59.7677 7.04583 59.4991 6.7772 59.1677 6.7772 C 58.8363 6.7772 58.5677 7.04583 58.5677 7.3772 C 58.5677 7.70857 58.8363 7.9772 59.1677 7.9772 C 59.4991 7.9772 59.7677 7.70857 59.7677 7.3772 M 51.2637 41.812 C 51.2637 41.4806 50.9951 41.212 50.6637 41.212 C 50.3323 41.212 50.0637 41.4806 50.0637 41.812 C 50.0637 42.1434 50.3323 42.412 50.6637 42.412 C 50.9951 42.412 51.2637 42.1434 51.2637 41.812 M 51.2637 46.892 C 51.2637 46.5606 50.9951 46.292 50.6637 46.292 C 50.3323 46.292 50.0637 46.5606 50.0637 46.892 C 50.0637 47.2234 50.3323 47.492 50.6637 47.492 C 50.9951 47.492 51.2637 47.2234 51.2637 46.892 M 50.3906 62.8464 C 50.3906 62.515 50.122 62.2464 49.7906 62.2464 C 49.4592 62.2464 49.1906 62.515 49.1906 62.8464 C 49.1906 63.1778 49.4592 63.4464 49.7906 63.4464 C 50.122 63.4464 50.3906 63.1778 50.3906 62.8464 M 50.3906 67.9264 C 50.3906 67.595 50.122 67.3264 49.7906 67.3264 C 49.4592 67.3264 49.1906 67.595 49.1906 67.9264 C 49.1906 68.2578 49.4592 68.5264 49.7906 68.5264 C 50.122 68.5264 50.3906 68.2578 50.3906 67.9264 M 119.215 54.4877 C 119.215 54.1563 118.946 53.8877 118.615 53.8877 C 118.283 53.8877 118.015 54.1563 118.015 54.4877 C 118.015 54.8191 118.283 55.0877 118.615 55.0877 C 118.946 55.0877 119.215 54.8191 119.215 54.4877 M 119.215 49.4077 C 119.215 49.0763 118.946 48.8077 118.615 48.8077 C 118.283 48.8077 118.015 49.0763 118.015 49.4077 C 118.015 49.7391 118.283 50.0077 118.615 50.0077 C 118.946 50.0077 119.215 49.7391 119.215 49.4077 M 119.215 44.3277 C 119.215 43.9963 118.946 43.7277 118.615 43.7277 C 118.283 43.7277 118.015 43.9963 118.015 44.3277 C 118.015 44.6591 118.283 44.9277 118.615 44.9277 C 118.946 44.9277 119.215 44.6591 119.215 44.3277 M 5.4775 2.3717 C 5.4775 1.46043 4.73877 0.7217 3.8275 0.7217 C 2.91623 0.7217 2.1775 1.46043 2.1775 2.3717 C 2.1775 3.28297 2.91623 4.0217 3.8275 4.0217 C 4.73877 4.0217 5.4775 3.28297 5.4775 2.3717 M 10.4813 14.0557 C 10.4813 13.1444 9.74257 12.4057 8.8313 12.4057 C 7.92003 12.4057 7.1813 13.1444 7.1813 14.0557 C 7.1813 14.967 7.92003 15.7057 8.8313 15.7057 C 9.74257 15.7057 10.4813 14.967 10.4813 14.0557 M 21.9113 14.0557 C 21.9113 13.1444 21.1726 12.4057 20.2613 12.4057 C 19.35 12.4057 18.6113 13.1444 18.6113 14.0557 C 18.6113 14.967 19.35 15.7057 20.2613 15.7057 C 21.1726 15.7057 21.9113 14.967 21.9113 14.0557 M 64.4563 39.2017 C 64.4563 38.2904 63.7176 37.5517 62.8063 37.5517 C 61.895 37.5517 61.1563 38.2904 61.1563 39.2017 C 61.1563 40.113 61.895 40.8517 62.8063 40.8517 C 63.7176 40.8517 64.4563 40.113 64.4563 39.2017 M 76.3181 10.8299 C 76.3181 9.91863 75.5794 9.1799 74.6681 9.1799 C 73.7568 9.1799 73.0181 9.91863 73.0181 10.8299 C 73.0181 11.7412 73.7568 12.4799 74.6681 12.4799 C 75.5794 12.4799 76.3181 11.7412 76.3181 10.8299 M 120.717 17.9165 C 120.717 17.0052 119.979 16.2665 119.067 16.2665 C 118.156 16.2665 117.417 17.0052 117.417 17.9165 C 117.417 18.8278 118.156 19.5665 119.067 19.5665 C 119.979 19.5665 120.717 18.8278 120.717 17.9165 M 123.588 2.3717 C 123.588 1.46043 122.849 0.7217 121.938 0.7217 C 121.026 0.7217 120.287 1.46043 120.287 2.3717 C 120.287 3.28297 121.026 4.0217 121.938 4.0217 C 122.849 4.0217 123.588 3.28297 123.588 2.3717 M 73.8289 70.7231 C 73.8289 69.8118 73.0902 69.0731 72.1789 69.0731 C 71.2676 69.0731 70.5289 69.8118 70.5289 70.7231 C 70.5289 71.6344 71.2676 72.3731 72.1789 72.3731 C 73.0902 72.3731 73.8289 71.6344 73.8289 70.7231 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" >
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 0.001335 57.1737 C 0.000611326 57.6053 0.342416 57.9597 0.773785 57.9745 L 0.79942 57.975 L 17.7699 58.0157 C 18.3212 58.017 18.7675 58.4644 18.7675 59.0157 L 18.7675 76.4727 C 18.7675 76.685 18.8518 76.8885 19.0019 77.0385 C 19.1521 77.1886 19.3556 77.2728 19.5679 77.2727 L 105.325 77.2323 C 105.766 77.2321 106.124 76.874 106.124 76.4323 L 106.124 59.1769 C 106.124 58.6246 106.572 58.1769 107.124 58.1769 L 124.392 58.1769 C 124.834 58.1769 125.192 57.8187 125.192 57.3769 L 125.192 0.8 C 125.192 0.358172 124.834 0 124.392 0 L 0.895565 0 C 0.454255 -1.11388e-006 0.0962964 0.357361 0.09556 0.79867 L 0.001335 57.1737 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

my desire Out put is as shown below.

[image]

and now what I am getting is something like as shown below. Also drawing is shifting downside when applying fe-composite.

[image]

Does anybody can guide me what I am missing or where I did mistake. And why data is shifting down side after applying fe-composite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the alignment issues, just add

```
x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"
```

so the `<feImage>` filter primitives line up with their originals.  Otherwise, they will be placed and size using the default values of `x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%"`.

As for the operations, I'm not sure I can help much, because I don't know what

```
comp-op=" dst-out dst-in"
```

is supposed to mean.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1599px; height: 888px; position: absolute;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="myfilter">
            <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="#layer1" result="lay1"/>
            <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="#layer2" result="lay2"/>
            <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="#layer3" result="lay3"/>
            <feImage x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="#layer4" result="lay4"/>

            <feComposite operator="in" in="lay2" in2="lay1" result="lay1in3"/>
            <!-- <feComposite operator="out" in2="lay3" in="laylin3" result="lay1in4" /> -->
            <feComposite operator="over" in="lay4" in2="lay1in3" /> -->
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g filter="url(#myfilter)" alignment-baseline="middle" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" text-anchor="middle">
        <svg id="layer1" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g comp-op=" dst-in">
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(217, 217, 52, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(217, 217, 52, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" comp-op=" src-over">
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 0.001335 57.1737 C 0.000611326 57.6053 0.342416 57.9597 0.773785 57.9745 L 0.79942 57.975 L 17.7699 58.0157 C 18.3212 58.017 18.7675 58.4644 18.7675 59.0157 L 18.7675 76.4727 C 18.7675 76.685 18.8518 76.8885 19.0019 77.0385 C 19.1521 77.1886 19.3556 77.2728 19.5679 77.2727 L 105.325 77.2323 C 105.766 77.2321 106.124 76.874 106.124 76.4323 L 106.124 59.1769 C 106.124 58.6246 106.572 58.1769 107.124 58.1769 L 124.392 58.1769 C 124.834 58.1769 125.192 57.8187 125.192 57.3769 L 125.192 0.8 C 125.192 0.358172 124.834 0 124.392 0 L 0.895565 0 C 0.454255 -1.11388e-006 0.0962964 0.357361 0.09556 0.79867 L 0.001335 57.1737 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="layer2" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g comp-op=" dst-out dst-in">
                <rect style="fill: rgb(5, 134, 48); stroke: #000000;" x="0" y="0" width="1599" height="888" />
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g>
                        <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                            <g fill="rgba(5, 134, 48, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(5, 134, 48, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" comp-op=" src-over">
                                <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 5.6025 2.3717 C 5.6025 1.39139 4.80781 0.5967 3.8275 0.5967 C 2.84719 0.5967 2.0525 1.39139 2.0525 2.3717 C 2.0525 3.35201 2.84719 4.1467 3.8275 4.1467 C 4.80781 4.1467 5.6025 3.35201 5.6025 2.3717 M 10.6063 14.0557 C 10.6063 13.0754 9.81161 12.2807 8.8313 12.2807 C 7.85099 12.2807 7.0563 13.0754 7.0563 14.0557 C 7.0563 15.036 7.85099 15.8307 8.8313 15.8307 C 9.81161 15.8307 10.6063 15.036 10.6063 14.0557 M 22.0363 14.0557 C 22.0363 13.0754 21.2416 12.2807 20.2613 12.2807 C 19.281 12.2807 18.4863 13.0754 18.4863 14.0557 C 18.4863 15.036 19.281 15.8307 20.2613 15.8307 C 21.2416 15.8307 22.0363 15.036 22.0363 14.0557 M 64.5813 39.2017 C 64.5813 38.2214 63.7866 37.4267 62.8063 37.4267 C 61.826 37.4267 61.0313 38.2214 61.0313 39.2017 C 61.0313 40.182 61.826 40.9767 62.8063 40.9767 C 63.7866 40.9767 64.5813 40.182 64.5813 39.2017 M 76.4431 10.8299 C 76.4431 9.84959 75.6484 9.0549 74.6681 9.0549 C 73.6878 9.0549 72.8931 9.84959 72.8931 10.8299 C 72.8931 11.8102 73.6878 12.6049 74.6681 12.6049 C 75.6484 12.6049 76.4431 11.8102 76.4431 10.8299 M 120.842 17.9165 C 120.842 16.9362 120.048 16.1415 119.067 16.1415 C 118.087 16.1415 117.292 16.9362 117.292 17.9165 C 117.292 18.8968 118.087 19.6915 119.067 19.6915 C 120.048 19.6915 120.842 18.8968 120.842 17.9165 M 123.713 2.3717 C 123.713 1.39139 122.918 0.5967 121.938 0.5967 C 120.957 0.5967 120.162 1.39139 120.162 2.3717 C 120.162 3.35201 120.957 4.1467 121.938 4.1467 C 122.918 4.1467 123.713 3.35201 123.713 2.3717 M 73.9539 70.7231 C 73.9539 69.7428 73.1592 68.9481 72.1789 68.9481 C 71.1986 68.9481 70.4039 69.7428 70.4039 70.7231 C 70.4039 71.7034 71.1986 72.4981 72.1789 72.4981 C 73.1592 72.4981 73.9539 71.7034 73.9539 70.7231 M 10.6741 20.3557 C 10.6741 20.0658 10.439 19.8307 10.1491 19.8307 C 9.85915 19.8307 9.6241 20.0658 9.6241 20.3557 C 9.6241 20.6456 9.85915 20.8807 10.1491 20.8807 C 10.439 20.8807 10.6741 20.6456 10.6741 20.3557 M 13.2141 20.3557 C 13.2141 20.0658 12.979 19.8307 12.6891 19.8307 C 12.3992 19.8307 12.1641 20.0658 12.1641 20.3557 C 12.1641 20.6456 12.3992 20.8807 12.6891 20.8807 C 12.979 20.8807 13.2141 20.6456 13.2141 20.3557 M 15.7541 20.3557 C 15.7541 20.0658 15.519 19.8307 15.2291 19.8307 C 14.9392 19.8307 14.7041 20.0658 14.7041 20.3557 C 14.7041 20.6456 14.9392 20.8807 15.2291 20.8807 C 15.519 20.8807 15.7541 20.6456 15.7541 20.3557 M 18.2941 20.3557 C 18.2941 20.0658 18.059 19.8307 17.7691 19.8307 C 17.4792 19.8307 17.2441 20.0658 17.2441 20.3557 C 17.2441 20.6456 17.4792 20.8807 17.7691 20.8807 C 18.059 20.8807 18.2941 20.6456 18.2941 20.3557 M 19.5641 22.8957 C 19.5641 22.6058 19.3291 22.3707 19.0391 22.3707 C 18.7492 22.3707 18.5141 22.6058 18.5141 22.8957 C 18.5141 23.1856 18.7492 23.4207 19.0391 23.4207 C 19.3291 23.4207 19.5641 23.1856 19.5641 22.8957 M 17.0241 22.8957 C 17.0241 22.6058 16.789 22.3707 16.4991 22.3707 C 16.2092 22.3707 15.9741 22.6058 15.9741 22.8957 C 15.9741 23.1856 16.2092 23.4207 16.4991 23.4207 C 16.789 23.4207 17.0241 23.1856 17.0241 22.8957 M 14.4841 22.8957 C 14.4841 22.6058 14.249 22.3707 13.9591 22.3707 C 13.6692 22.3707 13.4341 22.6058 13.4341 22.8957 C 13.4341 23.1856 13.6692 23.4207 13.9591 23.4207 C 14.249 23.4207 14.4841 23.1856 14.4841 22.8957 M 11.9441 22.8957 C 11.9441 22.6058 11.709 22.3707 11.4191 22.3707 C 11.1292 22.3707 10.8941 22.6058 10.8941 22.8957 C 10.8941 23.1856 11.1292 23.4207 11.4191 23.4207 C 11.709 23.4207 11.9441 23.1856 11.9441 22.8957 M 49.7327 7.3772 C 49.7327 6.97679 49.4081 6.6522 49.0077 6.6522 C 48.6073 6.6522 48.2827 6.97679 48.2827 7.3772 C 48.2827 7.77761 48.6073 8.1022 49.0077 8.1022 C 49.4081 8.1022 49.7327 7.77761 49.7327 7.3772 M 54.8127 7.3772 C 54.8127 6.97679 54.4881 6.6522 54.0877 6.6522 C 53.6873 6.6522 53.3627 6.97679 53.3627 7.3772 C 53.3627 7.77761 53.6873 8.1022 54.0877 8.1022 C 54.4881 8.1022 54.8127 7.77761 54.8127 7.3772 M 59.8927 7.3772 C 59.8927 6.97679 59.5681 6.6522 59.1677 6.6522 C 58.7673 6.6522 58.4427 6.97679 58.4427 7.3772 C 58.4427 7.77761 58.7673 8.1022 59.1677 8.1022 C 59.5681 8.1022 59.8927 7.77761 59.8927 7.3772 M 51.3887 41.812 C 51.3887 41.4116 51.0641 41.087 50.6637 41.087 C 50.2633 41.087 49.9387 41.4116 49.9387 41.812 C 49.9387 42.2124 50.2633 42.537 50.6637 42.537 C 51.0641 42.537 51.3887 42.2124 51.3887 41.812 M 51.3887 46.892 C 51.3887 46.4916 51.0641 46.167 50.6637 46.167 C 50.2633 46.167 49.9387 46.4916 49.9387 46.892 C 49.9387 47.2924 50.2633 47.617 50.6637 47.617 C 51.0641 47.617 51.3887 47.2924 51.3887 46.892 M 50.5156 62.8464 C 50.5156 62.446 50.191 62.1214 49.7906 62.1214 C 49.3902 62.1214 49.0656 62.446 49.0656 62.8464 C 49.0656 63.2468 49.3902 63.5714 49.7906 63.5714 C 50.191 63.5714 50.5156 63.2468 50.5156 62.8464 M 50.5156 67.9264 C 50.5156 67.526 50.191 67.2014 49.7906 67.2014 C 49.3902 67.2014 49.0656 67.526 49.0656 67.9264 C 49.0656 68.3268 49.3902 68.6514 49.7906 68.6514 C 50.191 68.6514 50.5156 68.3268 50.5156 67.9264 M 119.34 54.4877 C 119.34 54.0873 119.015 53.7627 118.615 53.7627 C 118.214 53.7627 117.89 54.0873 117.89 54.4877 C 117.89 54.8881 118.214 55.2127 118.615 55.2127 C 119.015 55.2127 119.34 54.8881 119.34 54.4877 M 119.34 49.4077 C 119.34 49.0073 119.015 48.6827 118.615 48.6827 C 118.214 48.6827 117.89 49.0073 117.89 49.4077 C 117.89 49.8081 118.214 50.1327 118.615 50.1327 C 119.015 50.1327 119.34 49.8081 119.34 49.4077 M 119.34 44.3277 C 119.34 43.9273 119.015 43.6027 118.615 43.6027 C 118.214 43.6027 117.89 43.9273 117.89 44.3277 C 117.89 44.7281 118.214 45.0527 118.615 45.0527 C 119.015 45.0527 119.34 44.7281 119.34 44.3277 M 18.6175 77.1231 L 18.6175 77.4231 L 18.9175 77.4231 L 18.9175 77.1231 L 18.6175 77.1231 M 105.974 77.0819 L 105.974 77.3819 L 106.274 77.3819 L 106.274 77.0819 L 105.974 77.0819 M 125.042 -0.15 L 125.042 0.15 L 125.342 0.15 L 125.342 -0.15 L 125.042 -0.15 M -0.0531 -0.15 L -0.0531 0.15 L 0.2469 0.15 L 0.2469 -0.15 L -0.0531 -0.15 Z" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="layer3" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
            <g comp-op=" dst-in">
                <svg id="layer4" style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(227, 227, 227, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(227, 227, 227, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" comp-op=" src-over">
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 10.5491 20.3557 C 10.5491 20.1348 10.37 19.9557 10.1491 19.9557 C 9.92819 19.9557 9.7491 20.1348 9.7491 20.3557 C 9.7491 20.5766 9.92819 20.7557 10.1491 20.7557 C 10.37 20.7557 10.5491 20.5766 10.5491 20.3557 M 13.0891 20.3557 C 13.0891 20.1348 12.91 19.9557 12.6891 19.9557 C 12.4682 19.9557 12.2891 20.1348 12.2891 20.3557 C 12.2891 20.5766 12.4682 20.7557 12.6891 20.7557 C 12.91 20.7557 13.0891 20.5766 13.0891 20.3557 M 15.6291 20.3557 C 15.6291 20.1348 15.45 19.9557 15.2291 19.9557 C 15.0082 19.9557 14.8291 20.1348 14.8291 20.3557 C 14.8291 20.5766 15.0082 20.7557 15.2291 20.7557 C 15.45 20.7557 15.6291 20.5766 15.6291 20.3557 M 18.1691 20.3557 C 18.1691 20.1348 17.99 19.9557 17.7691 19.9557 C 17.5482 19.9557 17.3691 20.1348 17.3691 20.3557 C 17.3691 20.5766 17.5482 20.7557 17.7691 20.7557 C 17.99 20.7557 18.1691 20.5766 18.1691 20.3557 M 19.4391 22.8957 C 19.4391 22.6748 19.26 22.4957 19.0391 22.4957 C 18.8182 22.4957 18.6391 22.6748 18.6391 22.8957 C 18.6391 23.1166 18.8182 23.2957 19.0391 23.2957 C 19.26 23.2957 19.4391 23.1166 19.4391 22.8957 M 16.8991 22.8957 C 16.8991 22.6748 16.72 22.4957 16.4991 22.4957 C 16.2782 22.4957 16.0991 22.6748 16.0991 22.8957 C 16.0991 23.1166 16.2782 23.2957 16.4991 23.2957 C 16.72 23.2957 16.8991 23.1166 16.8991 22.8957 M 14.3591 22.8957 C 14.3591 22.6748 14.18 22.4957 13.9591 22.4957 C 13.7382 22.4957 13.5591 22.6748 13.5591 22.8957 C 13.5591 23.1166 13.7382 23.2957 13.9591 23.2957 C 14.18 23.2957 14.3591 23.1166 14.3591 22.8957 M 11.8191 22.8957 C 11.8191 22.6748 11.64 22.4957 11.4191 22.4957 C 11.1982 22.4957 11.0191 22.6748 11.0191 22.8957 C 11.0191 23.1166 11.1982 23.2957 11.4191 23.2957 C 11.64 23.2957 11.8191 23.1166 11.8191 22.8957 M 49.6077 7.3772 C 49.6077 7.04583 49.3391 6.7772 49.0077 6.7772 C 48.6763 6.7772 48.4077 7.04583 48.4077 7.3772 C 48.4077 7.70857 48.6763 7.9772 49.0077 7.9772 C 49.3391 7.9772 49.6077 7.70857 49.6077 7.3772 M 54.6877 7.3772 C 54.6877 7.04583 54.4191 6.7772 54.0877 6.7772 C 53.7563 6.7772 53.4877 7.04583 53.4877 7.3772 C 53.4877 7.70857 53.7563 7.9772 54.0877 7.9772 C 54.4191 7.9772 54.6877 7.70857 54.6877 7.3772 M 59.7677 7.3772 C 59.7677 7.04583 59.4991 6.7772 59.1677 6.7772 C 58.8363 6.7772 58.5677 7.04583 58.5677 7.3772 C 58.5677 7.70857 58.8363 7.9772 59.1677 7.9772 C 59.4991 7.9772 59.7677 7.70857 59.7677 7.3772 M 51.2637 41.812 C 51.2637 41.4806 50.9951 41.212 50.6637 41.212 C 50.3323 41.212 50.0637 41.4806 50.0637 41.812 C 50.0637 42.1434 50.3323 42.412 50.6637 42.412 C 50.9951 42.412 51.2637 42.1434 51.2637 41.812 M 51.2637 46.892 C 51.2637 46.5606 50.9951 46.292 50.6637 46.292 C 50.3323 46.292 50.0637 46.5606 50.0637 46.892 C 50.0637 47.2234 50.3323 47.492 50.6637 47.492 C 50.9951 47.492 51.2637 47.2234 51.2637 46.892 M 50.3906 62.8464 C 50.3906 62.515 50.122 62.2464 49.7906 62.2464 C 49.4592 62.2464 49.1906 62.515 49.1906 62.8464 C 49.1906 63.1778 49.4592 63.4464 49.7906 63.4464 C 50.122 63.4464 50.3906 63.1778 50.3906 62.8464 M 50.3906 67.9264 C 50.3906 67.595 50.122 67.3264 49.7906 67.3264 C 49.4592 67.3264 49.1906 67.595 49.1906 67.9264 C 49.1906 68.2578 49.4592 68.5264 49.7906 68.5264 C 50.122 68.5264 50.3906 68.2578 50.3906 67.9264 M 119.215 54.4877 C 119.215 54.1563 118.946 53.8877 118.615 53.8877 C 118.283 53.8877 118.015 54.1563 118.015 54.4877 C 118.015 54.8191 118.283 55.0877 118.615 55.0877 C 118.946 55.0877 119.215 54.8191 119.215 54.4877 M 119.215 49.4077 C 119.215 49.0763 118.946 48.8077 118.615 48.8077 C 118.283 48.8077 118.015 49.0763 118.015 49.4077 C 118.015 49.7391 118.283 50.0077 118.615 50.0077 C 118.946 50.0077 119.215 49.7391 119.215 49.4077 M 119.215 44.3277 C 119.215 43.9963 118.946 43.7277 118.615 43.7277 C 118.283 43.7277 118.015 43.9963 118.015 44.3277 C 118.015 44.6591 118.283 44.9277 118.615 44.9277 C 118.946 44.9277 119.215 44.6591 119.215 44.3277 M 5.4775 2.3717 C 5.4775 1.46043 4.73877 0.7217 3.8275 0.7217 C 2.91623 0.7217 2.1775 1.46043 2.1775 2.3717 C 2.1775 3.28297 2.91623 4.0217 3.8275 4.0217 C 4.73877 4.0217 5.4775 3.28297 5.4775 2.3717 M 10.4813 14.0557 C 10.4813 13.1444 9.74257 12.4057 8.8313 12.4057 C 7.92003 12.4057 7.1813 13.1444 7.1813 14.0557 C 7.1813 14.967 7.92003 15.7057 8.8313 15.7057 C 9.74257 15.7057 10.4813 14.967 10.4813 14.0557 M 21.9113 14.0557 C 21.9113 13.1444 21.1726 12.4057 20.2613 12.4057 C 19.35 12.4057 18.6113 13.1444 18.6113 14.0557 C 18.6113 14.967 19.35 15.7057 20.2613 15.7057 C 21.1726 15.7057 21.9113 14.967 21.9113 14.0557 M 64.4563 39.2017 C 64.4563 38.2904 63.7176 37.5517 62.8063 37.5517 C 61.895 37.5517 61.1563 38.2904 61.1563 39.2017 C 61.1563 40.113 61.895 40.8517 62.8063 40.8517 C 63.7176 40.8517 64.4563 40.113 64.4563 39.2017 M 76.3181 10.8299 C 76.3181 9.91863 75.5794 9.1799 74.6681 9.1799 C 73.7568 9.1799 73.0181 9.91863 73.0181 10.8299 C 73.0181 11.7412 73.7568 12.4799 74.6681 12.4799 C 75.5794 12.4799 76.3181 11.7412 76.3181 10.8299 M 120.717 17.9165 C 120.717 17.0052 119.979 16.2665 119.067 16.2665 C 118.156 16.2665 117.417 17.0052 117.417 17.9165 C 117.417 18.8278 118.156 19.5665 119.067 19.5665 C 119.979 19.5665 120.717 18.8278 120.717 17.9165 M 123.588 2.3717 C 123.588 1.46043 122.849 0.7217 121.938 0.7217 C 121.026 0.7217 120.287 1.46043 120.287 2.3717 C 120.287 3.28297 121.026 4.0217 121.938 4.0217 C 122.849 4.0217 123.588 3.28297 123.588 2.3717 M 73.8289 70.7231 C 73.8289 69.8118 73.0902 69.0731 72.1789 69.0731 C 71.2676 69.0731 70.5289 69.8118 70.5289 70.7231 C 70.5289 71.6344 71.2676 72.3731 72.1789 72.3731 C 73.0902 72.3731 73.8289 71.6344 73.8289 70.7231 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <svg style="width: 1599px; height: 888px;">
                    <g fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" stroke-opacity="1" transform="scale(11.1035 -11.1035) translate(0 -79.9745) skewX(0) skewY(0) rotate(0)" comp-op=" src-over">
                        <path stroke-width="0.0900614" d="M 0.001335 57.1737 C 0.000611326 57.6053 0.342416 57.9597 0.773785 57.9745 L 0.79942 57.975 L 17.7699 58.0157 C 18.3212 58.017 18.7675 58.4644 18.7675 59.0157 L 18.7675 76.4727 C 18.7675 76.685 18.8518 76.8885 19.0019 77.0385 C 19.1521 77.1886 19.3556 77.2728 19.5679 77.2727 L 105.325 77.2323 C 105.766 77.2321 106.124 76.874 106.124 76.4323 L 106.124 59.1769 C 106.124 58.6246 106.572 58.1769 107.124 58.1769 L 124.392 58.1769 C 124.834 58.1769 125.192 57.8187 125.192 57.3769 L 125.192 0.8 C 125.192 0.358172 124.834 0 124.392 0 L 0.895565 0 C 0.454255 -1.11388e-006 0.0962964 0.357361 0.09556 0.79867 L 0.001335 57.1737 Z" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `comp-op` is not a valid CSS property that I am aware of.  It must be specific to whatever software application you are using.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGCompositing/#comp-op-property although that spec is abandoned and I think comp-op is now mix-blend-mode

Comment: Hay @PaulLeBeau, ThankYou. it's again you to respond my query. In my question "comp-op" at every <g> node is only for reference that at which point of svg what composite operation I want to apply, "comp-op" doesn't work so I am trying to use fe-composite. I have removed  "comp-op" from my question and revised it. now as you can see in my desired output image there is inner yellow border ring in all holes, that I am not getting after your suggested solution. and yes drawing Shifting issue is solved after using x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" .